# How to bind DOM objects to a JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a simple game and struggling with how to bind my DOM objects to the JS objects that spawn them. This used to be very easy back in the days of Flash - the object and it's visual representation were one and same! What's the best way to do this with JS/HTML? Here's a stripped down example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<body>

    <div id="pond"></div>

</body>

<script>

    function fish() {
        this.genotype = 'GATTACA';        
        this.phenotype = '<div class="fish" onclick=reveal()></div>';
    }

    shark = new fish();

    $(shark.phenotype).appendTo("#pond");

    function reveal() {
        alert(this.genotype);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: perhaps `shark.boundElement = $(shark.phenotype).appendTo("#pond");` ... depends on what jquery appendTo returns I guess

Comment: *Here's a stripped down example of what I'm trying to do* You'll have to give us more than that. Try explaining it.

Comment: Use a modern framework that does binding, if you are learning JS development then jQuery is not the thing to be learning. You would be much better off using your time to learn Angular, Vue or React.

Comment: @AdrianBrand What would my code above look like in React?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.data()` to associate the object with the DOM element.

```js
function fish() {
  this.genotype = 'GATTACA';
  this.phenotype = '<div class="fish" onclick="reveal(this)">Click to see genotype</div>';
}

shark = new fish();
$(shark.phenotype).data('fish', shark).appendTo("#pond");
function reveal(element) {
  alert($(element).data('fish').genotype);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pond"></div>
```